# OAuth2: Using access token

Tags: security, oauth-2.0

I'm quite of new about issuing access tokens and I would like to know if any of you can help me clearing my question.

Is it considered a best practice to use only the access tokens at the server-side? I saw a tutorial of authorization flow in which this guy was passing the token through the hash(#) in URL, but this seems to be really insecure since it's available to the user.

On the other hand, how do you manage access token usage? I can think of two approaches.

1. Passing the access token to the client and storing it using an encrypted cookie since I read that localStorage is not recommended.
2. Using the access token only in the server-side and call the API endpoint from client. Thus, managing all data in server-side and returning to client the "final result".

This questions is kinda newbie but I'd love to read your opinions. Also I would appreciate if you can share any resources (videos, books, blogs) you think may be of help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you talking about tokens issued by you for your own use being available to your users (how would this be a problem?), or your access token consumed by third party services on your behalf? Can you please provide some more context?

Comment: Yes! The second one, for example let's say that I'm using third party authentication like Google to use the access token in Firebase, or Spotify's authentication to create something on behalf the user.